# PCs on domain show notifications to add network printers

Tags: networking, printer, notifications

I am experiencing an issue which occasionally crops up, the issue is some PCs on our domain appear to have an issue where if a user logs into a PC they might experience an issue with repeated notifications of printers that are available.

These notifications can hit into the hundreds before they eventually stop. They appear in the Windows 10 notifications tray and bog down the PC until it finishes.

What I can't understand is this does not happen to every computer, only happens to some PCs.

It's as if the PC is scanning the network and finding every networked printer. I've tried to disable network discovery on the PCs but this does nothing to help.

If anyone has any ideas I would be forever grateful.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot if such notification ?

Comment: So I can't provide a screenshot as such currently as I don't have one to hand but I found one which resembles what it looks like online. https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fh30434.www3.hp.com%2Ft5%2Fimage%2Fserverpage%2Fimage-id%2F167669iDE8BA68E78E04BBB%2Fimage-size%2Flarge%3Fv%3Dv2%26px%3D999&tbnid=f39KFx36yp7jDM&vet=1&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fh30434.www3.hp.com%2Ft5%2FPrinter-Setup-Software-Drivers%2FStop-HP-printer-notification-on-win-10%2Ftd-p%2F6398445&docid=1r3e_mm4Vro2QM&w=384&h=800&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim